# how to set chartit-django to render a 3d pie chart

Tags: python, django, highcharts

i am trying to render a 3d pie chart with chartit_django. i am on Django 1.6.

my code in views.py :

```
def sales_pie_chart(request):
    ds = DataPool(
        series=[
            {
                'options': {
                'source': Sale.objects.values('sales_client__client_name').annotate(
                    sales_total_quantity=Sum('sales_total_quantity'))},
                'terms': [
                    'sales_client__client_name', 'sales_total_quantity'
                ]
            }
        ]
    )

    cht = Chart(
        datasource=ds,
        series_options=[
            {
                'options': {
                    'type': 'pie', 'stacking': False,
                    'options3d': {'enabled': True, 'alpha': 45, 'beta': 0}
                }, 'terms': {'sales_client__client_name': ['sales_total_quantity']}
            }
        ],
        chart_options={
            'title': {'text': 'Sales Report - Pie Chart'}
        }
    )
    return render(request, 'accounting/charts.html', {'cht': cht})
```

i am betting on the 'options3d' setting but cant seem to find any documentation online.
this code would only give a flat pie chart.

Comment: In case when you use any wrapper for django, please ensure if this wrapper supports new highcharts option (like 3d) and if you have correct version (4.0.x)

Comment: @SebastianBochan i am using version 4.0.4, i am asking how to enable 3d rendering in my Python/Django code... is it possible or not?

Comment: Do you use wrapper of highcharts for django or not?

Comment: okay... i use a library called Chartit if this what you mean by wrapper @SebastianBochan. do you recommend other wrappers?

Comment: So please contact with authors of this wrapper.